# hive query to remove minimum values from a table

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have a table with schema t(***`a`***,b,c) in hive.
I have to select all the rows whose `a` is not the minimum in t

I tried

```
select * from t where a>(select min(a) from t limit 1);

select * from t where t.a not in (select min(a) from t limit 1);
```

both of them failed .. How can I achieve this in hive and what is the generalization of error in above statements?

Edit :  `with , IN , exists` are not supported in my hive version .. so please refrain from using these in your answer

Answer (score 0):

try the below query

select A.* from t A left join (select min(a) as min from t) B where A.a>B.min

Subqueries inside a WHERE clause are not supported in Hive

check this 
[Write a nested select statement with a where clause in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454564/write-a-nested-select-statement-with-a-where-clause-in-hive)

i think the new version supports subqueries

Thanks